# Run main.c twice in xcode ide

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to run main.c twice in the xcode ide? How do I do it? For example, I need to run socket-server.c and then socket-client.c (in that order) when both files are called by one main.c file. main.c pseudocode:

```
int main()
{
    if (socket-server-running) {
        run socket-client
    } else {
        run socket-server
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have done this using intellij and webstorm so I assume it will be possible.

Comment: sorry you seem to be confused. Get a book about C. files are not functions.

Comment: @Daij-Djan please improve my question, I still think there is a valid question underneath all that confused terminology. Should I have said: "execute the compiled project twice?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two schemes (product menu tab) and executed them in order from the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the IDE to run the `main` twice.  The OS is not going to call your `main` like the way you think.

If you are going with that design, you need to modify your main to launch a second thread.